# Have we probed beyond Extremely Low Frequency (ELF) light to see is there is anything out in the universe emitting it?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I could only find some articles talking about radios used to communicate with submarines and a few now-defunct transmission towers for ELF. I would think this would be something that was studied to see if anything produced such frequencies in the universe but I couldn't find anything.

Do we see emissions in the electromagnetic spectrum just drop off at a certain point and that is why the research isn't going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extremely low frequencies (anything below kHz) cannot travel through interplanetary space, because the
[plasma frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation) is too high.

The plasma frequency is given by
$$\nu_p = \left( \frac{e^2 n_e}{4\pi^2 \epsilon_0 m_e}\right)^{1/2} = 9000 \left(\frac{n_e}{{\rm cm}^{-3}}\right)^{1/2}\ {\rm Hz},$$
where $n_e$ is the electron number density and $m_e$ is the electron mass. If waves have a frequency below the plasma frequency then they will be reflected.

The value of $n_e$ varies from place to place. In the Earth's ionosphere, typical values might be $n_e \sim 10^{5}$ to $10^{6}$ cm$^{-3}$. This means that waves with $\nu <$ a few MHz from outer space will not penetrate the Earth's ionosphere.

Even if we could put a radio telescope in space (or on the Moon?), there are sufficient electrons in the interplanetary medium near the Earth ($n_e \sim 10$ cm$^{-3}$) that waves with $\nu < 30$ kHz will not reach it from outer space.